# Re-arranging an matrix of numbers to a numeric list

Tags: vba, excel

If I have an array of numbers like this:

```
1  3  4  6  7
1  2
2  4  5  9
5  7
1  2  3  5
```

Is there a quick way to take all of the unique numbers and arrange them into a single column, like this?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
```

The approach I have works, but takes a very long time for large matrix:

```
Sub Test1
Call RecordArrange
Call RemoveDuplicates2
End Sub

Private Sub RecordArrange()
Worksheets("List").Activate
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

While i <= lastRow

Set Rng = Range("A" & i)

If IsEmpty(Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = False Then
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy
Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Else: i = i + 1

End If
Wend
Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A8000")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDuplicates2()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

While i <= lastRow
Set Rng = Range("A" & i)

If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

ElseIf Rng <> Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
i = i + 1
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
i = i + 1
Else: i = i + 1

End If

Wend
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This does work, but it seems like a very roundabout approach. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of unique members of a matrix (or 2 dimensional array), one good option is to use a dictionary (vba's hashtable/hashmap).  Since vba is lacking a ['set'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) data structure, a dictionary will do the job just fine.

if you have a 2 dimensional array (or matrix), you can just do a for each on that array.

```
For Each member in matrix
    someDictionary(member) = True
Next
```

I am setting the value of the dictionary to `True` but I could just as well set it to anything (we don't care about the value in this case).  What we do care about is the *key*.  After doing this, you will have filled the dictionary with just the *unique* list of items in the matrix.

After this loop you can just call `someDictionary.Keys` to get an array of the unique items.  You can then sort that array however you like.

*note that to use Dictionaries you will have to add a Reference to the Scripting library.

--

so for example:

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates2()

    Dim Rng As Variant: Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim cell as Variant
    Dim output as New Dictionary

    For Each cell in Rng
        output(cell) = True
    Next

    Dim uniques as Variant: uniques = output.Keys

    ' Do something with your array of uniques here
    ' perhaps drop to the worksheet like this
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1,UBound(uniques)+1)) = uniques

End Sub
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I'm not quite sure I follow the first part, though. Do I set the first line as "For each cell in Range" having defined the matrix as the whole range? Or is 'Matrix' a VBA term for something else?

Comment: I updated my response with some more code, see if that helps.  I would say that in VBA we talk more about a 'matrix' as a 2 dimensional array, but I know what you mean when you say 'matrix'.

Comment: Ah, ok. When I used the word, I meant it as a spread of numbers, just like those in the first example. In your script, I'm getting a compile error for New Dictionary, saying "User Defined Type not Defined." 

(Also, Rng is equal to ActiveSheet, rather than ActiveWorksheet).

I'm not familiar with Dictionaries, but I can see where this is coming from. Thanks a million.

Comment: Don't forget that you will add to have to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in your references (Tools -> References) in order to use Dictionaries.  That is likely what is causing the error.  Good catch on the ActiveSheet thing.. I always screw that up! :)

Comment: This works perfectly! One more thing, though. Is it possible to change the Output to be a column, rather than a row, as is here? If not, I can add a transposition command myself. 

Cheers!

Comment: instead of `= uniques` do `= WorksheetFunction.Transpose(uinques)`

Answer (score 4):

I started writing this before the other answer was posted - it's a good answer.

I would also use a dictionary because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MatrixToColumn()

    Dim myMatrix As Range
    Set myMatrix = Range("A1:E5")
    Dim myDictionary As Object
    Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    rowNumber = 1
    Dim Key As Variant

    For Each myCell In myMatrix
        If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then myDictionary(myCell.Value) = 1
    Next

    If myDictionary.Count > 1 Then
       For Each Key In myDictionary.keys
            Cells(rowNumber, 10) = Key
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Now, to review your code.

- **Indenting**, none of your code is indented. It's good practice to indent *all of your code* that way `Labels` will stick out as obvious.
- **`Sub Test1`** - I know you're just testing, but that's a very bad name for a sub.
- **`Call`** - You don't need to `Call` subs, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`
- **`Worksheets("List").Activate`** - Be sure to avoid things like `.Activate` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros .
- **`lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`** this isn't a great way to do this, the standard way is `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1161309) on SO by a very talented excel MVP
- Everything you're doing **on the sheet** can be done in the code, in a dictionary or at least in an array. That increases speed by a significant amount
- **`Dim Rng`** - it's a bad name and it doesn't follow [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) which has`camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.
- *Variable names* - give your variables meaningful names. Instead of `Rng` you could make it `myMatrix` or something similar.

---

For future reference:

```
If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

ElseIf Rng <> Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
i = i + 1
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
i = i + 1
Else: i = i + 1

End If
```

This piece of code can be optimized

```
If Not IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
    If Rng = Rng.Offset(1) Then Rng.Delete shift:=xlUp
Else: i = i + 1
End If
```

---

Your `While` loops aren't the preferred way in VBA; instead use a `For` loop-

```
For i = 1 to lastRow
Next
```

---

```
If IsEmpty(Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = False Then
```

I prefer to use a `Not` instead of `If False` because `If` usually checks for `True`

```
If Not IsEmpty(rng.offset(,1)) then
```

---

Instead of calculating `lastRow` twice, just pass it from one sub to the other

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates2(ByVal lastRow as Long)
```

Now you can

```
RemoveDuplicates2 lastRow
```

You could even pass your range as well

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates(ByVal lastRow as Long, ByVal myRange as Range)
```

---

This isn't great either

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
```

Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (F4) and the `(Name)` field can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("List")` and instead just use `List`.

Comment: I like your approach of using `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` to get around needing to add the reference library!  I keep telling myself I should do that more when I answer questions here (makes life simpler).

Comment: I will also add that AFAIK you don't need to check the count before entering the for each.  If the dictionary is empty, it will not execute the for each.  Also, a for each iterates through the keys by default, so you don't need to do `myDictionary.keys`, instead you can just do `myDictionary` and avoid generating the `.keys` array needlessly.